# Shape TextDirection=Vertical is not available in Excel

Tags: excel

I'm using Excel (Microsoft® Excel® for Microsoft 365 MSO (Version 2305 Build 16.0.16501.20074) 64-bit) on Windows OS (with English US locale). And I observed that the Shape TextDirection=Vertical is not available in my version of Excel.

Can anyone help why is this option not available in Excel?

Checked with my colleagues with same Excel version, and some of them have this option, while other don't.
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The option "Vertical" is available after installing any of the CJK language pack.
[image]

Comment: Good find. Thank you for posting this answer. You should be able to mark it as the answer now, so others can find it more easily.

Answer (score 0):

**Rotate all text 90 degrees** seems to do what you want. Looks like the names for the options have changed since the version you are using.

[image]

Comment: Yeah, seems so. But I'm not able to find the version with this change. Tried the following versions of Microsoft® Excel® for Microsoft 365 MSO and they show the option.  
Version **2307** Build 16.0.16610.20000,  
Version **2307** Build 16.0.16610.20000 JP,  
Version **2305** Build 16.0.16501.20074 CN,  
Version **2109** Build 16.0.14430.20256.

Comment: But a few machines with Excel version 2305 doesn't show it.